# Posting a mini-puzzle for a hint for another puzzle

Tags: discussion, questions

I created a $Word^{TM}$ kind of puzzle, and while trying to create a hint, I ended up with a mini-puzzle.

Is it ok if I post it as a new question, to make it available not just for the people interested in the first puzzle, but also for those not interested in $Word^{TM}$ kind of puzzles?

Or is it better to keep it just in the main puzzle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your mini-puzzle is a decent standalone puzzle on its own, I think it's fine to post it as a separate puzzle.  But if it can't stand on its own (needs to reference the main puzzle, or the answer doesn't make any sense without the context of the main puzzle, or it's just not sufficiently interesting on its own), then I would keep it as just a hint on the main puzzle.